# Passing/Specifty A Property In Generic Method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, func

I am trying to move some code that I wrote to a more generic method. While the method is longer, the part I am having trouble with is the following :

```
public static void Test()

{    
           MyObjectType[] list1 = ListMyObjectTypeMethod1();
            MyObjectType[] list2 = ListMyObjectTypeMethod2();

            List<MyObjectType> linqAblelist1 = new List<MyObjectType>(list1);
            List<MyObjectType> linqAblelist2 = new List<MyObjectType>(list2);

            IEnumerable<MyObjectType> toBeAdded = linqAblelist1.Where(x => linqAblelist2.All(y => y.Property1 != x.Property1));
            IEnumerable<MyObjectType> toBeDeleted = linqAblelist2.Where(a => linqAblelist1.All(b => b.Property1 != a.Property1));

}
```

And I am trying to pass in a generic type for MyObjectType, but where I have [How To Set Property Here?] how does one specify that in a parameter for the method?

```
public static void Test<T>(T[] x, T[] y)
        {
            List<T> list1 = new List<T>(x);
            List<T> list2 = new List<T>(y);
            IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded = list1.Where(x => list2.All(y => y.[How To Set Property Here?] != x.[How To Set Property Here?]));
            IEnumerable<T> toBeDeleted = list2.Where(a => list1.All(b => b.[How To Set Property Here?])); != a.[How To Set Property Here?]));));

        }
```

Comment: Do you really need a generic method ? since what you are doing in your method seems to be specific to a type.

Comment: +1 for a short and concrete example.

Comment: if you can change the underlying types, you should just move `property1 {get;}` and `property2 {get;}` in an interface

Comment: @Habib he could be working against an interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass in the selection of the property as a `Func<T, TProperty>`:

```
public static void Test<T, TProperty>(T[] x, T[] y, Func<T, TProperty> propertySelector)
    {
        List<T> list1 = new List<T>(x);
        List<T> list2 = new List<T>(y);
        IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded = list1.Where(x => list2.All(y => !propertySelector(y).Equals(propertySelector(x))));
        IEnumerable<T> toBeDeleted = list2.Where(a => !list1.All(b => propertySelector(b).Equals(propertySelector(a))));

    }
```

Then you can call it by specifying a lambda expression for `propertySelector`:

```
Test(someArray, someOtherArray, t => t.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: This would get around having to have an interface constraint. +1 Good idea.

Comment: I get a cannot apply operator compiler error with this code. Exact error is cannot apply operator between TProperty and TProperty.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to introduce a generic type constraint that will make sure `T` either inherits from a specific class or implements an interface. In either case the class or interface have to declare `Property1`. E.g. like this:

```
public static void Test<T>(T[] x, T[] y) where T : IHasProperty1
{
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some constraints on your generic type.

```
public static void Test<T>(T[] x, T[] y) where T : <SomeInterface>
{
   List<T> list1 = new List<T>(x);
   List<T> list2 = new List<T>(y);
   IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded = list1.Where(x => list2.All(y => y.PropertyName != x.PropertyName));
    IEnumerable<T> toBeDeleted = list2.Where(a => list1.All(b => b.PropertyName)); != a.PropertyName));));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann add a generic constraint that will ensure that `T` will have the properties you're expecting.  Some thing like:

```
public static void Test<T>(T[] x, T[] y) where T : MyObjectType
{
    List<T> list1 = new List<T>(x);
    List<T> list2 = new List<T>(y);
    IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded = list1.Where(x => list2.All(y => y.Property1  != x.Property1 ));
    IEnumerable<T> toBeDeleted = list2.Where(a => list1.All(b => b.Property1 )); != a.[How To Set Property Here?]));));

}
```

Comment: Might as well just get rid of the generics if you are going to constrain T to being an implementation of the object.